# Math::Random::MT compilation failed

Tags: macos, perl, compiler-errors, compilation, perl-module

I've been trying to compile Math::Random::MT module on my macos but I get the following error

```
In file included from MT.xs:2:
/Users/imac/opt/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h:694:10: fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found
#include <sys/types.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [MT.o] Error 1
  FANGLY/Math-Random-MT-1.17.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
```

I tried forcing the installation but to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated.

Najoua

Comment: It looks like your OS is missing the file `/usr/include/sys/types.h`. Not knowing much about MacOS I can't advise how you would go about installing that file, but it seems to be a MacOS configuration issue rather than a perl issue.

Comment: Thanks Dave for your reply. I would say yes, I don't even have include folder in /usr. But If it is the case will it affect only some modules and not others ? Because I installed other perl modules with no problem.

Comment: I believe that I found the types.h file in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h` Any idea on how to make the compiler find the folder in its right place ?

Comment: Which command did you run to install `Math::Random::MT` ?

Comment: I used `sudo cpan install Math::Random::MT ` and I also tried with the `-f ` to force installing it

Comment: @NajouaMghazli See also [Conda-installed Perl cannot find "sys/types.h" when compiling C extension](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/24709)

Comment: Thank you @HåkonHægland. I'm trying to install it through conda as suggested in the link above but it's taking an eternity. I'll comment here once the installation is complete to let you know if it worked.

Comment: Didn't work, it worked on my WSL ubuntu 18.4 but not on macOS